# How do I get consistent spacing around an mbox?

Tags: spacing, boxes

I am trying to typeset a formula in LaTeX with a rule name beneath it, such as the following:

[image: Desired output]

The code for the rule an automatically-generated mess (not necessarily using maths mode), output from the theorem prover [Isabelle/HOL](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/), which I have little control over. My hope was that I could somehow isolate the auto-generated output by using `mbox` or something similar.

My attempt to generate a macro for generating this output boils down to something like the following once I remove formatting commands:

```
\newcommand{\myrule}[2]{{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
      \mbox{#1} \\
      \mbox{#2}
  \end{minipage}}}
```

This can then be used as `\myrule{\AutoGeneratedOutput}{ParitalPrimeSuc}`.

The problem I have is that the vertical space between the two boxes depends on the content of the first box. For example, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myrule}[2]{{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \mbox{#1} \\
        \mbox{#2}
    \end{minipage}}}

\newcommand{\myruleii}[2]{{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \fbox{#1} \\
        \fbox{#2}
    \end{minipage}\ignorespacesafterend}}

\myrule{\begin{minipage}{1in}line 1\end{minipage}}{last line}

\vspace*{.5in}

\myrule{\begin{minipage}{1in}line 1\\ line 2\end{minipage}}{last line}

\vspace*{.5in}

\myruleii{\begin{minipage}{1in}line 1\end{minipage}}{last line}

\vspace*{.5in}

\myruleii{\begin{minipage}{1in}line 1\\ line 2\end{minipage}}{last line}

\end{document}
```

The output of this is as follows (images moved to save space):

[image: Actual output]

Note that the distance between the bottom of the first `mbox` and the second `mbox` (highlighted in blue) differs depending on whether the first parameter has a line-break in it our not.

Interestingly, if I replace the `mbox` with a `fbox`, the spacing becomes consistent (highlighted in green). This confuses me somewhat, because [an `fbox` is supposed to be the same as an `mbox`, other than having a border around it](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#framebox).

Is there a way to get the consistent spacing of `fbox` without the border? (Or should I be using a completely different mechanism for this?)

Answer (score 6):

`\begin{minipage}[b]` should help. Then the reference point of the `minipage` is moved to the bottom element (e.g. line). Then the normal line spacing rules apply, trying `\baselineskip` for the base lines first.

Otherwise the reference point is vertically in the middle. With several lines the depth of the `minipage` becomes huge and very likely exceeds `\lineskiplimit`. Then TeX does not set the space according to `\baselineskip`. Instead it inserts `\lineskip` (default: 1pt).

Comment: Thanks for your post. So using `\fbox` solves my problem simply because the border pushes me over `\lineskiplimit`? Using `\begin{minipage}[b]` appears to  solve the problem, but after reading up on `\lineskiplimit`, `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` (which led me to `\offinterlineskip`), I wonder if adjusting these is a better approach?

Comment: @davidg: The distance between the two `\fbox`es is not larger in your image. The space between the lines is very likely `\lineskip` = `1pt`. The space *inside* the `\fbox` does not matter. The dimension of the `\fbox` is visible by its lines. The spacing inside is controlled by `\fboxsep`. Therefore `\fbox` is larger by `\fboxsep` + `\fboxrule` in all four directions than a `\mbox` with the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

you could try putting a `\strut` at the end of the last line in the first box,
and another at the beginning of the first line in the second box.

that should enforce the equivalent of a `\baselineskip` between them.